# Can't access \SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Tags: c#

I using System.Win32 to write registry code:

```
RegistryKey startup = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", true);
startup.SetValue("hi", "Test");
```

But when I open registry editor, I not write in `\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` but the key write in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the key you are writing to. The problem is you are either

- Trying to write to a 64bit key from a 32bit application

or

- Trying to write to a 32bit key from a 64bit application

---

You can do this 2 ways

- `RegistryView.Registry64` / `RegistryView.Registry32` and `OpenBaseKey` in .Net 4 and above
- `RegOpenKeyEx` Api call in `Advapi32.dll` with the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY`/`KEY_WOW64_32KEY` flag in earlier versions

> **RegistryView Enumeration** : On the 64-bit version of Windows, portions of the registry are stored
>   separately for 32-bit and 64-bit applications. There is a 32-bit view
>   for 32-bit applications and a 64-bit view for 64-bit applications.
>
> You can specify a registry view when you use the OpenBaseKey and
>   OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive, String, RegistryView) methods, and the
>   FromHandle property on a RegistryKey object.

---

**Code** using Registry64

```
var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
//var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
if (baseKey != null)
{
    var subKey = baseKey.OpenSubKey("myKey", 
                         RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, 
                         RegistryRights.FullControl);

    if (subKey != null)
    {
        subKey.SetValue("hi", "Test");
        subKey.Close();
    }

    baseKey.Close();
}
```

---

**PInvoke** using `RegOpenKeyEx` and `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` can be found here

[PInvoke RegOpenKeyEx (advapi32)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/RegOpenKeyEx.html)

---

**Additional Resources**

[RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey Method (RegistryHive, RegistryView)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey(v=vs.110).aspx)

[RegistryKey.OpenSubKey Method (String, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck, RegistryRights)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128502(v=vs.110).aspx)

[RegistryView Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Registry Key Security and Access Rights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724878(v=vs.85).aspx)

[32-bit and 64-bit Application Data in the Registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx)